# Multi-Line Watch Window in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When debugging XML, it's a pain the butt to constantly click on the Text/XML visualizers in the Watch Window to see the full value of an XML string variable.  The "Watch" windows in Visual Studio seem to be constrained to one line.

Is there a way to constantly "watch" the value of a multi-line variable when debugging?  Doesn't have to be in a watch window i suppose, but I want to see the value of an XML string, and the visualizer boxes are modal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very pretty, but one way I have dealt with that is to put the string address in a memory window, which can show text characters.  Open one of the memory windows from the Debug menu:  Debug\Windows\Memory.  You can then type in the address or the variable name or just double click on the variable and "drag" it up to the address field of the memory window.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is change the autoexp.dat so it will display the hash of the string first, so at least you know when the string changes. That way you don't need to open the visualizer box as often. Of course this will not work when the multi-line string is continually being updated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is asking about Visual Studio 2010, but in Visual Studio 2013, you can right-click on the string variable row in the Autos/Locals/Watch pane and select **Add Parallel Watch**.  This will give you a non-modal, multi-line view of the string variable value.

Comment: In VS 2015 this still gives me a single line view.  Is there something else I need to click for a multi-line view of my string value (the little magnifier aside)?