# Visual Studio - inserting multi-line expressions into Watch Window while debugging

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

While debugging in Visual Studio, how can I insert multi-line expressions into Watch Window, so that each line is not broken into a separate INVALID watch expression. This is really frustrating because I have many expressions spanning multiple lines that I need to watch. Note that both Pin to Source and Immediate Window do not work for tracking multiple values from many places in source code.

e.g.

```
PyFunc1(Py.kw("var1", var1),
        Py.kw("var2", var2))
```

gets broken to:

```
PyFunc1(Py.kw("var1", var1),
```

and

```
Py.kw("var2", var2))
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't remove the newlines before pasting the expressions in the watch window?

Comment: because VS has to do it for me :)

Comment: Try pasting into the Immediate window instead.  It tends to work better for longer expressions.

Comment: @PatrickNelson-MSFT this puts all the indendation spaces to expression in Immediate Window! Not a good workaround at all, besides I need to watch multiple values.

Comment: "I have many expressions spanning multiple lines that I need to watch" - might one suggest that this code is in need of refactoring if it needs this much complexity to debug it?

Comment: The code above is pretty valid and spans multiple lines. I do not see a need for refactoring and flooding code with temporary variables, just because of VS limitation/bug.

Comment: Have a look at OzCode's [Magic Glance](http://o.oz-code.com/features#simplify) feature - it can show results of expressions even without Watch or Immediate windows

Comment: @AlekseyL. this is like automatic "Pin To Source", but will not work when the variables are scattered throughout the code, so need to be watched in one window

Comment: Strangely enough, the Quick Watch command is working correctly.

Comment: @IvanStoev please post this as answer because Quick Watch solves my problem, it is easy to add normal watch from quick watch window.

Comment: @denfromufa I will be happy to do it, but unfortunately although the Quick Watch shows correctly the expression and the value in the list, the Expression combo shows only the first line, and more importantly, neither Add Watch button or list item context menu works - they produce the same multi error lines in Watch window. Consistency :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Repro

I dont think this is "By-Design", its just unavailable "out-of-the-box".

I agree, it'd be better behaviour for multi-line calls to be added to the Watch Window using line terminators instead of new lines:

[image]

---

## Research

I found this similar question with a few "workarounds" to choose from:
[Multi-Line Watch Window in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448451/multi-line-watch-window-in-visual-studio-2010)

I also found this comment in the [MSDN Forums by a MSFT Engineer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5852feb6-5ad6-4d40-9dc0-838fe6b71823/how-to-edit-multiline-strings-in-watch-window?forum=vsdebug):

> I’m afraid that it is not supported, we often edit them one by one. Maybe you could submit this feature request: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio

---

## Roll your own Visual Studio Add-In

So I had a go at it myself, this is *by no means* production code but it shows you how to do it:

*(click image to enlarge)*

[image]

```
namespace AddinMultiLineWatch
{
public class Connect : IDTExtensibility2, IDTCommandTarget
{
    //ADD THESE MEMBER VARIABLES
    //private DebuggerEvents _debuggerEvents = null;
    //private _dispDebuggerEvents_OnEnterBreakModeEventHandler DebuggerEvents_OnEnterBreakMode;
    private Window _watchWindow = null;
    private CommandEvents _objCommandEvents;
    private bool _isRecursive = false;
    public Connect()
    {
    }

    public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)
    {
        _applicationObject = (DTE2)application;
        _addInInstance = (AddIn)addInInst;

        //SET THE MEMBER VARIABLES
        //_debuggerEvents = _applicationObject.Events.DebuggerEvents;
        //_debuggerEvents.OnEnterBreakMode += new _dispDebuggerEvents_OnEnterBreakModeEventHandler(BreakHandler);
        //var watchWindow = _applicationObject.Windows.Item(EnvDTE.Constants.vsWindowKindWatch);
        _objCommandEvents = _applicationObject.Events.CommandEvents;
        _objCommandEvents.BeforeExecute += new _dispCommandEvents_BeforeExecuteEventHandler(BeforeExecute);

        if(connectMode == ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_UISetup)
        {
            object []contextGUIDS = new object[] { };
            Commands2 commands = (Commands2)_applicationObject.Commands;
            string toolsMenuName = "Tools";

            Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBar menuBarCommandBar = ((Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBars)_applicationObject.CommandBars)["MenuBar"];
ar:
            CommandBarControl toolsControl = menuBarCommandBar.Controls[toolsMenuName];
            CommandBarPopup toolsPopup = (CommandBarPopup)toolsControl;

            try
            {
                Command command = commands.AddNamedCommand2(_addInInstance, "AddinMultiLineWatch", "AddinMultiLineWatch", "Executes the command for AddinMultiLineWatch", true, 59, ref contextGUIDS, (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported+(int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled, (int)vsCommandStyle.vsCommandStylePictAndText, vsCommandControlType.vsCommandControlTypeButton);

                if((command != null) && (toolsPopup != null))
                {
                    command.AddControl(toolsPopup.CommandBar, 1);
                }
            }
            catch(System.ArgumentException)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    //ADD THIS METHOD TO INTERCEPT THE DEBUG.ADDWATCH COMMAND
    public void BeforeExecute(string Guid, int ID, object CustomIn, object CustomOut, ref bool CancelDefault)
    {
        EnvDTE.Command objCommand = default(EnvDTE.Command);
        try
        {
            objCommand = _applicationObject.Commands.Item(Guid, ID);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        if ((objCommand != null))
        {
            if (objCommand.Name == "Debug.AddWatch")
            {
                //if (_isRecursive) return;
                //_isRecursive = true;
                TextSelection selection = (TextSelection)_applicationObject.ActiveDocument.Selection;
                //TODO make selection goto next semi-colon/Line Terminator...
                var selText = selection.Text;  

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selText)) return;   
                //Only intercept multi-line Add Watch commands                    
                if (selText.Contains(Environment.NewLine))
                {
                  //THE BLACK MAGIC: make it fit in one line! lol
                  selText = selText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);              
                  //THIS CALL IS RECURSIVE, I'LL LEAVE IT TO THE READER AS AN EXERCISE TO SOLVE..
                _applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("Debug.AddWatch", selText);
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

1. Create a New Project > Other Project Types > Extensibility > Visual Studio Add-In > name it AddinMultiLineWatch
2. Go through the wizard
3. Add the code above to the Connect.cs class - see my //UPPERCASE comments with what stuff to add.
4. Put a break point on the line `TextSelection selection = (TextSelection)_applicationObject.ActiveDocument.Selection;`
5. Press F5 and a new instance of VS will launch > choose New Project > Console App > name it TestMultilineAddWatch
6. In the program.cs of the Console App, specify a code call over 2 lines and put a break point on it, as shown in the screenshot, eg:

   ```
   Add(1,            //Breakpoint here and select both lines
           2);
   }

   static int Add(int i, int j)
   {
       return i + j;
   }
   ```
7. F5 in the TestMultilineAddWatch solution and when the code control halts on the break point > select/highlight the two lines `Add(1, \r\n  2)` > right click > Add Watch
8. Clicking **Add Watch** in the VS IDE debugging context menu causes the VS AddinMultiLineWatch solution to intercept the call and activate, halting on the break point.... where you will see **the black magic** of *replacing multi lined code in to a single line* sent to the Watch Window.

The Visual Studio EXEC command calling itself makes this method recursive, if you debug it, exiting out of the recursion manually you will see the results as per my screenshot.

Happy debugging!

Answer (score 5):

You could do it using autohotkey and a custom key binding ( e.g. Alt+Shift+V)

!+v means Alt+Shift+v

The macro below:
If in devenv.exe, and you press Alt+Shift+V, edit the clipboard contents, removing /r/n and replace them with nothing, then press Ctrl+V to paste

I tested this out cutting and pasting in a text document in visual studio.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe devenv.exe
!+v::
FixString = %clipboard%
StringReplace, FixString, FixString,`r`n,,A
Clipboard := FixString
Send, ^v
```