# How to create custom extension for .sql file in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, editor, visual-studio-extensions

I’m very new to visual studio extensions. I have requirement to create a new extension for visual studio 2017 and this extension is for .sql file. If a solution has .sql file, and if user right-click on .sql file then i need to have new custom option to open file in word pad.

Any help or guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you right click on any sql file there is already an option to open in word pad. Are you missing some part of your question?

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Just right click on a File in Solution Explorer > Open With. Then simply configure it:

[image]

Visual Studio is one of the best IDE, if not the best, not sure why you want to use WordPad but at least this will save you from making an Extension.

---

If you really do want to make it, here is an example of how you can add Menu items to Context Menu's, it'll give you keywords to google:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBar menuBarCommandBar = ((Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBars)_applicationObject.CommandBars)["MenuBar"];

CommandBarControl toolsControl = menuBarCommandBar.Controls[toolsMenuName];
CommandBarPopup toolsPopup = (CommandBarPopup)toolsControl;


Command command = commands.AddNamedCommand2(_addInInstance, "AddinMultiLineWatch", "AddinMultiLineWatch", "Executes the command for AddinMultiLineWatch", true, 59, ref contextGUIDS, (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported+(int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled, (int)vsCommandStyle.vsCommandStylePictAndText, vsCommandControlType.vsCommandControlTypeButton);

if((command != null) && (toolsPopup != null))
{
    command.AddControl(toolsPopup.CommandBar, 1);
}
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38500621/495455

Answer (score 0):

Here are some resources where you could start.

- [visualstudioextensibility.com](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/overview/vs/)
- [Building extensions for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/ide/extensions/overview?view=vsts)
- [VS SDK Extensibility Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples)

I think you want to add a command to a context menu (of *Text editor* or *Solution Explorer*)