# Extension .vsix in Visual Studio 2022 Community preview - no errors but does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I am a beginner in C# and Visual Studio. I am trying to create an extension for Visual Studio 2022 Community (64-bit) - Preview
Version 17.7.0 Preview 2.0.

The extension is supposed to save a list of the opened files in Visual Studio into a text file.

- There are no errors in the code.
- I have successfully compiled it.
- I have installed the .vsix extension successfully.
- The extension is installed and activated correctly.
- I have created the folder `C:\my_ruta`, and it exists.
- I have created the file `vsc_opened.txt` in `C:\my_ruta`.
- I have restarted Visual Studio as an administrator.
- I have opened a file in Visual Studio.

It should have added the complete path of the opened file to `vsc_opened.txt`, but IT DOES NOTHING!

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using Task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task;
using EnvDTE;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;
using System.Threading;

namespace OponedFilesHistory
{
    [PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true, AllowsBackgroundLoading = true)]
    [Guid("297ae94e-533e-4578-a588-27a29faff749")]
    [ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids.NoSolution)]
    [ProvideMenuResource("Menus.ctmenu", 1)]



    public static class PkgCmdIDList
    {

        public const int cmdidMyCommand = 0x100;
    }

    public sealed class OpenedFilesHistoryPackage : AsyncPackage
    {
        protected override async Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress<ServiceProgressData> progress)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("InitializeAsync called");

            await base.InitializeAsync(cancellationToken, progress);

            var mcs = await GetServiceAsync(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;

            if (mcs != null)
            {
                var menuCommandID = new CommandID(new Guid("297ae94e-533e-4578-a588-27a29faff749"), (int)PkgCmdIDList.cmdidMyCommand);
                var menuItem = new MenuCommand(MenuItemCallback, menuCommandID);
                mcs.AddCommand(menuItem);
            }
        }

        private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string logFile = @"C:\my_ruta\vsc_opened.txt";
            ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread(); //fix to the diagnostic
            EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)GetGlobalService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));

            foreach (EnvDTE.Document document in dte.Documents)
            {
                string fileName = document.FullName;
                File.AppendAllText(logFile, fileName + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: When you make VS Plugins you can run them in the debugger (F5) and it will spin up a new instance of VS, does that work?

Comment: When I click 'debugger', another window opens, an experimental instance of Visual Studio. In the new experimental window, under extensions -> installed, My Extension (OpenedFilesHistory) appears as installed and activated.

I added :
`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("InitializeAsync called");`

But it never appears in the debug messages (it's as if it's not being executed).

There are certain XAML errors, but from searching for information, I have been told that they are not related because my extension does not have any XAML.
Sorry for my English (automatically translated).

Comment: You're English is fine, if you can't get it working in the debugger instance then there's another problem. This is a bit old now, but this is the code I used to make them https://stackoverflow.com/a/38500621/495455